# Specifying database name with Eclipselink to SQLServer db?

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jpa, eclipselink

I'm new to ElcipseLink and JPA. I've successfully set up my persistence.xml and EclipseLink library. However, when trying to retrieve data from the server, I get invalid object name: dbo.Material.

My values are stored in the leermiddelen database. The scheme is dbo and the table is Material. When I try to specify the cataloge name (leermiddelen), then I get an error that specifying the database name is not supported in Azure.

A little help? (btw, when manually connection with a connection string and the driver from Microsoft, it does work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>models.Material</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and the java code:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction userTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    try {
        userTransaction.begin();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Material> materials = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e from Material e").getResultList();
        System.out.println("Getting materials list...");
        for (Iterator<Material> iterator = materials.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Material m = (Material) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(m.toString());
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

Finally the error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-04-05 11:16:13.426--UnitOfWork(1690796457)--Exception        [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Material'.
Error Code: 208
Call: SELECT Number, Amount, CanReserve, Description, Firm, IsAvailable, Name, PhotoUrl, Price FROM dbo.Material
```

Comment: how did you try to specify the database in your connection url? What was the error message?

Comment: maybe "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is not a valid URL?

Comment: I tried to specify the database name by adding java annotations @Table(.....)

Comment: include `database=leermiddelen;` in your connection url as shown here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/03/29/java-access-to-sql-azure-via-the-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: Thank you so much! Silly me :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion for the question. It seems that the issue was caused by the incorrect jdbc url. The jdbc url for Azure SQL Database is as below.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<database-name>;user=<username>@<hostname>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

For getting the connection string on Azure portal, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple-windows/#step-4-get-connection-string.